# How to add timezone to jQuery Countdown

Tags: jquery, html, timezone, countdown

I am using a countdown I found, which will countdown to the start of a livestream, so it is currently counting down to the time of the PC, whereas I want it to countdown to BST (25th August @ 9am) (UK Time).

Here is the HTML code, which I believe is all you need:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.lwtCountdown-1.0.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/misc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="countdown">
        <div class="dash weeks_dash">
            <span class="dash_title">weeks</span>
            <div class="digit">0</div>
            <div class="digit">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dash days_dash">
            <span class="dash_title">days</span>
            <div class="digit">0</div>
            <div class="digit">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dash hours_dash">
            <span class="dash_title">hours</span>
            <div class="digit">0</div>
            <div class="digit">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dash minutes_dash">
            <span class="dash_title">minutes</span>
            <div class="digit">0</div>
            <div class="digit">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="dash seconds_dash">
            <span class="dash_title">seconds</span>
            <div class="digit">0</div>
            <div class="digit">0</div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- end of countdown -->
    <!-- start of the javascript code that handles the countdown -->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $('#countdown').countDown({
                targetDate: {
                    'day':      25,
                    'month':    8,
                    'year':     2013,
                    'hour':     9,
                    'min':      0,
                    'sec':      0
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <!-- end of the javascript code that handles the countdown -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean [this component](http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown).  Next time, please provide a link so we don't have to search.

First determine the UTC time for your event.  There are *many* ways to do that, so I won't address them here unless that is specifically your issue.

The UTC time for the example you gave is 2013-08-05 8:00:00.

In their docs [here](http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/example.php?e=standart_time) they show how pass the time in UTC:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('#countdown').countDown({
        targetDate: {
            'day':      25,
            'month':    8,
            'year':     2013,
            'hour':     8,        // note the input time is in utc
            'min':      0,
            'sec':      0,
            'utc':      true      // set this parameter to true
            }
        });
    });
```

Digging into the source of the component itself, in `jquery.lwtCountdown-1.0.js`, there is a bug in this code:

```
if (options.targetDate)
{
    targetTime = new Date(options.targetDate.month + '/' + options.targetDate.day + '/' + options.targetDate.year + ' ' + options.targetDate.hour + ':' + options.targetDate.min + ':' + options.targetDate.sec + (options.targetDate.utc ? ' UTC' : ''));
}
```

They are creating a `Date` by assembling a date string that is hard-coded in mm/dd/yyyy format.   That will not work in places that use other date formats, such as the dd/mm/yyyy format used in the UK.  They should instead be passing separate parameters.  Change that code to this:

```
if (options.targetDate)
{
  var td = options.targetDate;
  if (options.targetDate.utc)
    targetTime = new Date(Date.UTC(td.year, td.month-1, td.day, td.hour, td.min, td.sec));
  else
    targetTime = new Date(td.year, td.month-1, td.day, td.hour, td.min, td.sec);
}
```

You should also report this bug back to the author.

Comment: That is not the source sadly, but I can't test if this works as I am not on my PC.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect then.  I'd like to help, but I am not a mind reader.  Can you point me at the component you are actually using???

Comment: You downloaded the same component from somewhere else.  So?  If you take the time to look at the source of the component, right at the top in comments there is a link to the original which is what I gave you to start with.

Comment: I created another question, as I downloaded the component you said instead, but the UTC function isn't working for me on that.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18161996/utc-countdown-couting-to-client-clock-not-utc

Comment: That is not proper etiquette for StackOverflow.  Please delete your other question and just edit this one if necessary.  And I'm not sure how else I can say this - ***THEY ARE THE SAME COMPONENT***  I just pointed at the author, and you pointed at someone *using* it.

Comment: This does not seem to countdown to UTC time, as when I changed the time on my computer, the time changes on the countdown.

Comment: There's no getting around that.  If your clock is not correct, the value will be wrong.